# Custom hook does not execute as expected

Tags: reactjs

In below code while giving empty array as second argument for useEffect it does not return value. but removing second argument give result. but it execute infinite

```
const useCurrentLocation = (options: GeoOptions | null) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<GeoPosition | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<GeoError | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocation = async () => {
      try {
        const location: GeoPosition = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          getCurrentPosition((loc) => {
            if (loc) {
              resolve(loc)
            }
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err)
            setError(err)
          }, options ? options : { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 })
        })

        if (location !== null) {
          setLocation(location);
        }
        else {
          setLocation(null);
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        setLocation(null);
        return null;
      }
    }
    fetchLocation()
  })
  return { location, error }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the second argument for the useEffect?

Comment: yes second argument for useEffect

Comment: You need to give it a dependency array or it will loop forever as you're setting state inside the hook.

Comment: I want to it execute only once